# Migration files in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am creating a model in rails (3.2.3) and am defining what columns are to be included (hope thats correct)

for example my first entry is

```
 t.string :Dish_Name
```

My first question is can I use that syntax i.e. Dish_Name ?

My second question is I want to use dropdowns to select options from the input field, so for exampel i would like to have a "Country of origin" with multiple options, countries of the world.

Would it be better to have a separate DB with all the countries in and then pull in the data from the dropdown? If so could someone point me in the right direction to see how to do this? not necessarily looking for the answer just a good place to start looking

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Leading uppercase names are reserved for constants. Typical column names are lowercase with underscores (e.g. `dish_name` or `country_of_origin`). These are Ruby conventions, and Rails follows along. Naming conventions matter in Ruby, unlike a language like C#, where you call anything just about anything with any casing you want.

Be sure to check out [guides.rubyonrails.org](http://guides.rubyonrails.org) for a lot more information.